# Changing Default dots argument in R

Tags: r, jsonlite

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895811/can-i-tell-the-r-plyr-package-to-work-in-parallel-by-default/9895903#9895903) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212245/change-default-arguments-of-an-r-function-at-runtime/55302390#55302390).

I need to assign a default to the `...` argument in a function. I have successfully been able to to use the [`default`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/default/index.html) package to accomplish this for specific arguments. For instance, lets say I want to allow `toJSON` from the [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) package to show more than four digits. The default is 4, but I want to show 10.

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(default)

df <- data.frame(x = 2:5, 
                 y = 2:5 / pi)
df
#>   x         y
#> 1 2 0.6366198
#> 2 3 0.9549297
#> 3 4 1.2732395
#> 4 5 1.5915494

# show as JSON - defaults to four digits
toJSON(df)
#> [{"x":2,"y":0.6366},{"x":3,"y":0.9549},{"x":4,"y":1.2732},{"x":5,"y":1.5915}]

# use default pacakge to change to 10
default(toJSON) <- list(digits = 10)

toJSON(df)
#> [{"x":2,"y":0.63661977237},{"x":3,"y":0.95492965855},{"x":4,"y":1.2732395447},{"x":5,"y":1.5915494309}]
```

There is another function called `stream_out` which uses `toJSON` but only uses the `digits` argument in `...`.

```r
> stream_out(df)
{"x":2,"y":0.63662}
{"x":3,"y":0.95493}
{"x":4,"y":1.27324}
{"x":5,"y":1.59155}
Complete! Processed total of 4 rows.
> 
> stream_out(df, digits = 10)
{"x":2,"y":0.63661977237}
{"x":3,"y":0.95492965855}
{"x":4,"y":1.2732395447}
{"x":5,"y":1.5915494309}
Complete! Processed total of 4 rows.
```

So even though I have changed the `digits` in `toJSON`, it isn't passed to the `...` in `stream_out`. I cannot change this in the same manner as with `toJSON`.

```r
> default(stream_out) <- list(digits = 10)
Error: 'digits' is not an argument of this function
```

This is not strictly a `jsonlite` question, but that is my use case here. I need to somehow change the `...` argument of the `stream_out` function so that any time it is used, 10 digits are returned, rather than 4. However, any examples that show how to change defaults of `...` arguments could probably be used to get to what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: tried coming up with a solution but can't help you. actually i think the default you want to change is [here](https://github.com/cran/jsonlite/blob/master/R/asJSON.numeric.R#L1) which would explain why the default you get from `stream_out` is 5 digits not 4 as in `toJSON`. typically one can [edit even internal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388570/how-to-modify-unexported-object-in-a-package) but again not working for this situation for some reason. also `formals(toJSON)$digits <- 10` is sufficient to change defaults, not sure why we needed a package for that

Comment: @rawr, thank you. I will tinker with the approach noted in your link. As an FYI, I realized this problem when investigating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69948248/r-bigrquery-losing-decimals-in-writing) I previously posted around using `R` with Google BigQuery. Sounds like it is a known issue in [`bigrquery`](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/issues/320). Thanks for some direction on this.